# PHP Font-Awesome Images not showing up

Tags: php, css, font-awesome

I am using a theme and the font-awesome images are not showing up. Any ideas as of why? Everything on the site functions, i just cannot see the font awesome images. I updated folder name bt changed links to reflect that.  Thanks

```
<!-- Theme CSS -->
<link href="../css/freelancer.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom Fonts -->
<link href="../vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Skip to main content

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-custom">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> Menu <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#page-top">T-Minus Retirement</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="hidden">
                    <a href="#page-top"></a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-scroll">
                    <a href="#portfolio">Dashboard</a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-scroll">
                    <a href="#month">Input Monthly Data</a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-scroll">
                    <a href="#update">Update</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

<!-- Header -->
<header>
    <div class="container" id="maincontent" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="../img/t.png" alt="">
                <div class="intro-text">
                    <h1 class="name">T-Minus Retirement</h1>
                    <hr class="star-light">
                    <span class="skills">Earn - Save - Retire</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: I don't see anything related to images or HTML or complete markup. All you included were css references and no php.

Comment: @Fred-ii- `<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <h2><?php echo $_SESSION['username']?>'s Dashboard</h2>
                    <hr class="star-primary">
                </div>
            </div>`   Here is an example of some code and the `<hr class="star-primary">` should show a hr with a star in the middle but it shoes up as a rectangle

Comment: if this is a php-related issue, try error reporting and check your paths

Answer (score 2):

It's unlikely that this is a PHP error unless you are using PHP to generate the HTML that should render the icons themselves. But if your output HTML is correct, then PHP did it's job and you aren't having any problems there.

More likely, there is a problem with your HTML/CSS. Typically Font Awesome icons can be loaded as icon web-fonts that use Font Awesome CSS. It looks like you are already linking to a Font Awesome directory in your HTML. To use the icons in CSS though, you need to give the HTML elements that you want to render the icon font the correct classes: `fa` and `fa-your-icon-name`. From the Font Awesome [website](http://fontawesome.io/examples/):

> You can place Font Awesome icons just about anywhere using the CSS
>   Prefix fa and the icon's name. Font Awesome is designed to be used
>   with inline elements (we like the  tag for brevity, but using a
>    is more semantically correct).
>
> `<i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i>`

If you're trying to make a star icon (as in your above comment), you would want to use `<i class="fa fa-star"></i>`. This should render an icon font that you can color and size right in your CSS. And because it's a vector-based font and not an image, it will never be pixelated.